# Denial of salary certificate

Tags: employment, india, labor-law, indian-penal-code

I was part of a small software product company for 4 years. I reported directly to the owner and I was paid a percentage of the profits of the company and a minimum fixed pay of 8LPA. I was paid mainly by cheque under the name of the company. The company doesn't have any financial wing and they don't have any salary slips or other proper documentation.

Now my next potential employer is asking for a salary slip, and I was denied of this. The company is giving me many reasons like this won't be a reason for you to get rejected, giving something like that after the tax year could get them in trouble and all.

- How important is this document in a hiring process?
- How can I present a salary slip which reflects my actual pay (fixed pay+ profit based pay)? This is crucial as the next offer will be heavily dependent on this number.
- What could I possibly do in a situation where I am denied of the salary slip or other documents (in India to be specific)?

Answer (score 1):

It's a easy one ..approach the new organisation and tell them about your problem genuinely and as you have stated that you received cheques from them produce a bank statement showing ur salary credited